# Copy subset of defined properties from one object to another

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I receive an object and it can have the following properties (as an example):

```
{
  "status": "PENDING",
  "owner": "UID",
  "createdOn": "2020-08-12",
  "modifiedOn": "2020-08-12"
}
```

I want to copy *some* of the properties (e.g. status and owner only) from that object to another object, but I only want to copy them if they are not undefined or null (i.e. they exist on the original object).

Obviously I can do:

```
  let copy = {};
  if(orig.status) copy['status'] = orig.status;
  if(orig.owner} copy['owner'] = orig.owner;
```

Or..

```
  let copy = {};
  orig.status && copy.status = orig.status;
  orig.owner && copy.owner = orig.owner;
```

But is there a more succint, easier way to do this. This is a simple example, in my actual use case, I need to copy around 10 properties.

I am using the latest typescript.

Thanks
Iain

Comment: If you only want to check for "not undefined or null" as opposed to "falsy", then you should use the [nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) instead of the [logical AND operator `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND).

Answer (score 1):

I create an array with all fields which should be copied and iterate with foreach over it. For all these properties I check if in the orioinal-object the prperty is neither undefined nor null. If both not I copy the property to the result-array.

```js
let obj = {
  "status": "PENDING",
  "owner": "UID",
  "createdOn": "2020-08-12",
  "modifiedOn": "2020-08-12",
  "nullish": null
};

let fields = ['status', 'owner', 'false', 'nullish'];
let copy = {};

fields.forEach(field => {
    if (obj[field] !== undefined && obj[field] !== null)
        copy[field] = obj[field];
});

console.log(copy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can do that without referring to a specific attribute in an "if" clause by iterating over the object keys:

This example shows an object before and after a search to remove null attributes:

```js
let myObject = {
  "status": "PENDING",
    "owner": "UID",
    "blankAttribute" : null,
    "createdOn": "2020-08-12",
    "modifiedOn": "2020-08-12"
}

console.log("Before null trim: ", myObject);

Object.keys(myObject).forEach(key => {
  if (myObject[key] === null) {
      delete myObject[key]
    }
});

console.log("After null trim: ",myObject);
```